# jquery timepicker not displaying dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-timepicker

I am using [jquery-timepicker](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/), and it is not displaying the dropdown when I click on the input box. In my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#StartTime').timepicker(); 
});
</script>
/* ... */
<div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
    <label>Start Time:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="StartTime" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

I know it is loading properly, because the ui-timepicker element is being added to the DOM when I click on the input box and it formats time entered in the box when it loses focus. It just isn't displaying the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have all the dependencies. I copied your code to a snippet and added the dependencies from [the official site](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) and it worked well. I included the following dependencies: jQuery, jQuery timepicker and Bootstrap timepicker. The last two have CSS and JS files too.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#StartTime').timepicker();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/lib/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

<div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
  <label>Start Time:</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="StartTime" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have all of those dependencies.

Comment: @MusicalShore Then you should post more code because you have empirical evidence over here that _the code itself_ you posted works.

Comment: Turns out I needed to build my .less file which contained the import.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there is no css definitions, which may hide this element.

Comment: That's definitely not happening, I checked in the debugger.